# Removing underline on links on wordpress site. text-decoration: none; doesn't work

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

Before you mark me as duplicate: I've read all the similar questions and tried the solutions and either I'm too dumb to understand them (a valid possibility), or my problem is different, but they didn't work for me.

I was marked off-topic on wordpress forum since it is apparently a css/html problem, so I reposted here.

*Now on to the problem:*

I'm having trouble with removing the underlines of some links I have on my site. Here's my html definition of the links:

```
<p style="text-align: center;">
    <a class="buttonL" href="http://cns.uni.lu/homel">&lt;</a>
    <a class="buttonR" href="http://cns.uni.lu/homer">&gt;</a>
</p>
```

And my CSS from the "custom CSS" page:

```
.buttonL {
    border-radius: 50%;
    position:fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 0%;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: none;
    color: grey;
    padding: 5px 20px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none !important;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 50px;
    margin: 4px 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-weight: 900;
}

.buttonR {
    border-radius: 50%;
    position:fixed;
    top: 50%;
    right: 0%;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: none;
    color: grey;
    padding: 5px 20px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none !important;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 50px;
    margin: 4px 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-weight: 900
}
```

I know it's redundant and inelegant. No use commenting on that. I can make it more elegant later.

For some reason, there is a line underneath the links, that won't go away. I've tried using

```
text-decoration:none !important;
```

, but to no avail. I've applied it on .buttonL, .buttonR, a, .buttonL a, .buttonR a, .buttonL:link, .buttonL:active, .buttonR:link, .buttonR:active, .buttonL a:link, .buttonL a:active, .buttonR a:link, .buttonR a:active.

I've also tried doing

```
border-bottom: none;
```

and

```
box-shadow: none;
```

, also to no avail.

Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong?

P.S. I can't link the page I'm referencing, as it is on an internal network. Sorry...

Here's a screenshot of the page:
[The links in question are the arrows to either sides. Although the other links have the same problem.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yhOVV.jpg)

Comment: Which browser? Because, I couldn't see the issue in my browser

Comment: wird! it is work perfect for me :|

Comment: `p .buttonL, p .buttonR  { text-decoration:none !important; }`  try something like this.

Comment: I'm using firefox as the network the site is running on only supports firefox (Don't ask why, because i don't know :)

Comment: Tried p .buttonL... just now. It doesn't change anything.

Comment: Works fine for me in firefox too. If possible, could you attach a screenshot in the question?

Comment: I added the screenshot. The links borders are rounded (don't really know why since the background is transparent), but there is a small line at the bottom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found the solution:

For some reason the background gradient (although it was white) left a line at the backgrounds border (or center - I'm not sure). To remove this, I added

```
.entry-content a{background-image:none;}
```

to the css file, instead of just making it transparent.

Thanks for all the help :D

Comment: Thank you for solving my problem. Putting background images to link texts sitewide is as horrible as it gets.

Answer (score 1):

Use This CSS may be help you thanks

```
   body .buttonL, body .buttonR {
        text-decoration: none !important;
    }
```

**OR USE THIS**

```
   body a{
        text-decoration: none !important;
    }
```

Comment: Sorry, but it didn't change anything.

Comment: body a{
        text-decoration: none !important;
    }
use this

Comment: Would a screenshot be helpful?

Comment: share me web URL

Comment: As I said in the question, you can't access the site as it is on an internal network of my university, so the url will lead you to page not found.

Comment: how can i debug it from my side i test your code its working fine

Comment: Try using *{ text-decoration:none !important;} just to see if it changes it

Comment: No, that didn't change it either. I get the feeling this has nothing to do with the code of the link...

Comment: Did you place it at the very bottom of the css code ?

Comment: Yes I did. I put it after everything else.

Comment: Try opening up chrome inspector tools and see if text-decoration works there, at the same time you’ll know exactly where to edit the real code , do you know how to use chrome dev tool?

Comment: No, but I can't open the site in chrome, because the internal network is restricted to firefox. It's a bit of a pain. When I look at the link with the object inspector, the text-decoration:none; part seems to be working.

Comment: That sucks , but I believe Firefox does have dev tools as well. Basically you can click on an element, and the code shows up , and you can edit there , like change the text color , etc, anything .  And it will tell you that the code is on line #150 etc. But it doesn’t make the changes to your actual code , once you refresh the browser it reverts back. YouTube Firefox developer tools tutorial, you should learn enough in 10 min to possibly find the issue

Comment: Thanks, will try that.

Comment: Ok, weird thing: I just noticed in the firefox inspector window, that background-position (on .entry-content a) seems to move the line up and down...

Comment: Also try clearing your cache , I would just open up a new “incognito “ tab..( chrome) , but Firefox should have something similar . Sometimes the cache is a huge pain

Answer (score 0):

If the css is not working means then use jquery

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.buttonL').css('text-decoration','none');
        $('.buttonR').css('text-decoration','none');
    });
<script>
```

I hope this will solve your issue.

Comment: How do I implement this? Where do I put it?

Comment: For some reason, all that did was break the whole site. Wordpress reformatted the code and made it unusable.

Comment: Ok I put the code in a different place (just before the links at hand) and it made them dissapear completely. Before it was at the very start of the file.

Comment: I added it in footer.php, at the bottom, just before the closing </php> tag and it still doesn't work. Thanks though :/

Answer (score 0):

A right-click-inspect might reveal that you do not have an underline issue, but rather:

box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 currentColor;

If that is the case (it was for me), then:

box-shadow:none; /* worked just fine for me. */